# When creating threads, some are getting a thread ID 0

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a server application that creates new thread for every incoming request.

However, every once in a while, it will create a thread with thread ID = 0 (used pthread_equal to check this). I have a structure that contains the thread ID that I pass to the function specified in pthread_create, and am checking this there.

Why would a thread get created with ID = 0?
Is there anything I can do if this happens? I cannot use this thread and want to exit it immediately.

=====================================================================

```
typedef struct 
{
    pthread_t tid;
    other_struct_t Other;
} data_ptr_t;

void * worker(void * arg)
{
    data_ptr_t local_data;
    data_ptr_t * incoming_data = (data_ptr_t *) arg;
    if (NULL == incoming_data || NULL == incoming_data->Other)
    {
        printf("invalid input\n");
    }
    else if (pthread_equal(incoming_data->tid, 0))
    {
        printf("invalid thread id\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // add to global thread pool
        // do other stuff here
        // remove from global thread pool
    }
}

int main()
{
    // server socket stuff
    while (1)
    {
        // if incoming connection is valid
        data_ptr_t data;
        int error = pthread_create(&(data.tid), NULL, (void * (*) (void *)) worker, (void *) &data);
        if (0 != errror)
        {
            printf("could not create thread (%d)\n", error);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_detach(data.tid);
            printf("thread dispatched\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** If the number of threads I'm creating is under 50 or so, it works fine. Upwards of 70, most threads go through just fine, the rest end up printing the "invalid thread id".

**Note:** This is on Linux.

Comment: Do you have any example code to illustrate your problem?

Comment: `pthread_t` is an opaque type.  It is not meaningful nor safe to treat it as an integer.

Comment: I've added some example code to show the gist of what my application is doing. Please let me know if there's something else you need.

Comment: @pilcrow is there any way to check it's validity?

Comment: ok , as far as I see here is something your while(1) is in main so u opening (endless) threads , Imo while should be in thread and u just want to send the data to the thread , so do the data recieve in while inside the thread, about thread id0 : according to msdn thread / process will receive pID 0 when it is about to shutdown.

Comment: No, this is on Linux.

Comment: Oh then I cant help you :) 
But I think you should think about comment above , your thread is to little its complexity O(1) so maybe thinks it is about to get closed so receives pID 0 , but again it would be correct on windowes box I am not sure about linux .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this:

```
while (1)
{
    // if incoming connection is valid
    data_ptr_t data;
    int error = pthread_create(&(data.tid), 
        NULL, (void * (*) (void *)) worker, (void *) &data);
```

your `data_ptr_t` is a local variable on the stack. On the next iteration of the `while` loop, that variable is destroyed/gone/not-valid.

The while loop might start another iteration long before the new `worker` thread starts running and makes use of the data you pass to it. Instead, dynamically allocate the `data` you pass to the worker thread so you can be sure it's still valid.

Comment: +1  ... and call `pthread_self()` if the worker needs to know its own thread ID!